# Tales of Vesperia's AI fails to recognize enemies' resistance attributes

Tags: tales-of-vesperia

I have been playing Tales of Vesperia for a while now and I noticed that it's a huge nuisance to have Rita in the party while fighting enemies with a resistance against one or more elements.
Even though an enemy has been scanned using a Magic Lens, Rita keeps using spells of their resistance attribute(s) on them, which is really annoying because it renders her attacks less effective and - most importantly - it decreases the Grade I earn from the battle(s).
Manually disabling the artes that conflict with the enemies' attributes is not really an option because switching artes around all the time just adds to the nuisance.

I don't remember facing such an issue in Tales of Symphonia.
I recently started a new ToS savegame and found that on a desert scorpion Genis diligently uses Icicle and never Fire Ball, whereas on desert thieves he also uses the latter (both enemies were scanned with Magic Lenses).

So, my question is: Am I missing something in Tales of Vesperia that I need to make the AI handle enemies' resistances intelligently? (Rita is the one who most often uses artes with elemental attributes, but it's essentially the same issue with every character, albeit to a lesser extent.) Or is this a bug or a case of "removed a cool useful feature"?